# can I get .class from generic type argument?

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have the following class:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T extends Object> {

    protected T createNewFromData(Reader reader){
        GSON.fromJSON(reader,T.class); // T.class isn't allowed :(
    }
}
```

How do I pass a Class<T> instance into there? Is there some wierd and wacky work around?

Is there a way to get a Class<T> reference other than from a pre-instantiated Object of type T? It won't let me do this either:

```
T t = new T();
Class<T> klass = t.class;
```

**Attempt #2**

Interestingly, if I remove the "extends JSONOBjBase" from the class definition, I simply get an unchecked cast WARNING (no error). Is there another way to write how the cast is done?

[image: eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of type erasure! See GSON's TypeTokens.

Comment: Cheers @SLaks. I updated my question with the answer based on your suggestions.

Comment: I don't think that solution will work; I think `TypeToken` has to be created with a concrete type, not a type variable, and that you really do have to pass the type token around.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I haven't run it yet but it compiles... :/

Comment: @MikeS: Louis is right.  I'm reasonably certain that that won't work.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it will help.

Comment: @LouisWasserman your right it didn't work. 'Object cannot be cast to MyType'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or you can send the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) as a constructor argument and use that object instead of trying to get T.class.

```
public abstract class MyClass<T extends Object> {

    private Class<T> klass;

    public MyClass(Class<T> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    protected T createNewFromData(Reader reader){
        GSON.fromJSON(reader,klass); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure you can : 
        public T createNewFormData(Reader reader, Class<T> clazz){
            Object a = null;
            if(clazz.isInstance(a)){
               System.out.println("Instance!!");
            };
            return null;
          }

And call it like this : 
       cls.createNewFormData(yourObject, Long.class);

Comment: Yeah and how do I pass the Class<T> into createNewFormData? T.class doesn't work.

Comment: This should be your method signature :  
public T createNewFormData(Reader reader, Class<T> clazz). 
When you call it, call it like this : 
GSON.fromJSON(reader,clazz); 
When you call your method use this : 
cls.createNewFormData(reader, YourRealClass.class);

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Answer (score 12):

No.
Due to type erasure, this information does not exist at runtime.

Instead, you can re-use GSON's [TypeToken hack](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html), which creates an anonymous class that inherits a closed generic base class.

Answer (score 0):

OK. This is how you should do it :

```
      public abstract class MyClass <T> {

        public T createNewFormData(Reader reader, Class<T> clazz){
        return GSON.fromJSON(reader, clazz);
        }
      }

      public class ImplementMyClass extends MyClass<Long>{
      }
```

And call it like this :

```
            MyClass<Long> cls = new ImplementMyClass();


    Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new  Socket("localhost", 8080);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    InputStream i = null;
    try {
        i = s.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(i);
    cls.createNewFormData(reader, Long.class);
```

Comment: Your first code block is in MyClass.java, and your 2nd is in MyClassImplementation.java. I need to do the calling of createNewFormData from within MyClass - which is impossible because of the limitations of generics in Java.

Comment: The second block is in arbitrary place like a static main() for example. I don't understand why this is not working for you, I have used this approach on several occasions.

Comment: If you read my OP you will see why it doesn't work. I need to pass in a T reference of T from WITHIN the abstract MyClass. So the implementing version of MyClass specifies 'T' to be something. From within MyClass I want to pass around T.class - but I can't.

Comment: OK... GSON.fromJSON(reader, clazz); is called from WITHIN the abstract class... The second batch of code is just showing how you should call your method in your abstract class... Even if you extend your abstract class, the call will still work and it will also be type-safe.

Comment: I'm not sure you are getting what I'm saying. You are doing cls.createNewFormData(reader, Long.class) and its all good and well doing Long.class but how do I do T.class from within the abstract class? You can't.

Comment: This is getting frustrating... You don't do T.class cause you can't. You use the !!!!clazz!!!! argument, that's why you send the Long.class as an argument to createNewFormData in the first place. The clazz variable is used to hold your type (i.e. T.class()) after the type erasure. If this is still unclear I give up.

Comment: We are IN MyClass.java (not some subclass with a populated generic argument) and I want to call createNewFormData but we can't because we don't know what T is and we can't do T.class. How is that not clear? P.S. I really appreciate you taking the time to try help me.

Comment: @MikeS - Check the "Second try", maybe this is what you needed :D. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: I've given it a go - please see the Attempt #2 addition to my original question. I think we are getting close!!

Comment: Sorry. My second example is not good (I got carried away). Because of type erasure you need an instance of T in order to capture the correct type. You need to modify your code like the first example and carry the Class<T> with you if you need that type information. That's why the GSon reader method asks for Class<T>. Add a constructor to your abstract class and request for Class<T> parameter in that constructor.

Comment: PS: Even the cast is not good, because casting this.getClass() to Class<T> will try to cast an instance of Class<MyClass<T>> to Class<T>, which is so wrong.

Comment: Yes I was hoping to not have to make an abstract method called getClassInstance() but I guess I have to. Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of echoes the answer given by Alex above. Here's a sample code where I'm writing a generic json -> POJO wrapper using the jackson library:

```
/* Method that reads json string from a file, and maps it to an instance of the class passed in as the second argument. */


public static <T> T getObjectMappedFromJsonInFile(String fileName, Class<T> clazz){

    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();

    File file=new File(fileName);

    try{

        JsonNode jsonNode=mapper.readTree(file);

        T response=mapper.convertValue(jsonNode,clazz);

        return response;
    }catch (Exception e){

        log.error("Error reading transactions.json file",e);

    }
    return null;

}
```

And here's how I call it:

```
TransactionsResponse response=getObjectMappedFromJsonInFile(fileName,TransactionsResponse.class);
```